# C# - FtpWebRequest - Multiple requests over the same connection/login

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to loop on a FTP folder for check if a file has arrived

I do:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost:8080");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

while(true)
{
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

But at the second iteration I get an exception:

> The stream cannot be read

Comment: Try using `using` statements or dispose response,responseStream and reader.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have update my code but I have always this exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I missed it, you're only issuing one request and trying to get a response multiple times. Try the code below:

```
while(true)
{
    FtpWebRequest request =     (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost:8080");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

You should add a pause of some sort at the end of each loop though. You don't want to bombard the server.

Comment: Yes , It works but I have to login again every time?

Comment: Each request is a separate entity. It's not really logging in, it's providing identification as to who is making the request. The `FtpWebRequest` class is a wrapper for Ftp calls but still uses web methodology, each request is it's own entity.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reuse the `FtpWebRequest` instance for multiple requests.

But as the `FtpWebRequest` works on top of a connection pool, it actually can reuse an underlying FTP connection. As long as the [`FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.keepalive) is set to its default value of `true`.

When the `KeepAlive` is set to `true`, the underlying FTP connection is not closed, when the request finishes. When you create another instance of the `FtpWebRequest` with the same URL, the connection is reused.

```
while (true)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost:8080");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    // reuse the connection (not necessary, as the true is the default)
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this precison on the `KeepAlive` property